# Web scraping, how to accept this google window

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hello I need some help to accept the google window

This is my code

```
PATH=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
web_google='https://www.google.com/'
google=driver.get(web_google)
cuadrado_close=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
```

I cant get 'accept' button'

I attach the image to accept button

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfxcz.png)

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure there is an "accept" button there. Chrome should display the page of interest. Then you can goto `more tools ==> developer tools` and get more information about the page. I found a sign in button and did `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in").click()`. I think some selenium tutorials will help!

Comment: I just attached the image thank you all tdelanay and Yun

Comment: No it isnt works for me I get this error:
    
    NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:            
    {"method":"css selector","selector":".next-dialog-close"}
    (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)